# Applying shades to an image while applying color

Tags: ios

I am changing the color of a car based on a 3 slider values for HSV. I am able to change the color but it feels like paint.There is no originality in the image after color change.How can i apply shades and to effects.

How can i apply the shades and effects as in input image.

Comment: Strange that you use RGB slider for HSV...Just to make sure, is the output "paint-like" if you only change *hue*?

Comment: @Mahm00d it is a just a slider taking hsv values. Ijust named them red green blue. thats all.

Comment: You didn't answer my question: what's your output like when you only change the hue and not the saturation/value? Because change in the *hue* wouldn't influence the "shade" or illumination changes on the shape, only the color.

Comment: @Mahm00d Yeah its only with hue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you can refer below code in C++, here I am changing only hue value and if you want to change saturation and value just create a Mat with the slider position value  and add or subtract with the appropriate channel(sat or val).

```
int H=50;  
Mat src, hsv, dst;
char window_name[30] = "HSV Demo";
void HSV_Demo( int, void* );


int main( int argc, char** argv ){

  src = imread( "car.jpg", 1 );
  namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  createTrackbar( "Hue", window_name,&H, 179, HSV_Demo );
  HSV_Demo( 0, 0 );

  while(true)
  {
    int c;
    c = waitKey( 20 );
    if( (char)c == 27 )
     break;

     if( (char)c == 's' ) imwrite("result.jpg",dst);

   }

}


void HSV_Demo( int, void* )
{
  cvtColor(src, hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
  Mat channel[3];
  split(hsv,channel);
  channel[0].setTo(H);
  Mat tmp[3] = { channel[0],channel[1],channel[2] };
  merge(tmp,3,dst);
  cvtColor(dst, dst,CV_HSV2BGR);
  imshow( window_name, dst );
}
```

[image: Color1] [image: Color2]
[image: Color3] [image: Color4]

**Edit:-**

Based on below comment here is the step to create black and white image using HSV by keeping shades.

Note that the below method is not  perfect as you can see the edges have irregularity, but you can try something like below or improve the below method itself.

The idea is simple we will consider only the value-channel and add up with some constant(slider position) to create white and subtract to create black, then convert this to BGR image using [cvtColor()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor). The shades may disappear if the addition or subtraction result out of bound.

Before adding or subtracting we will create a mask image by segmenting the hue(here red) and create a new Mat with the constant(slider position) and mask, so that the background remains unchanged while addition or subtraction.

```
void HSV_Demo( int, void* )
{
  cvtColor(src, hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
  Mat channel[3];
  split(hsv,channel);

   Mat thr1,thr2;
   inRange(hsv,Scalar(165,50,50),Scalar(179,255,255), thr1); //Create mask to change to avoid background
   inRange(hsv,Scalar(0,50,50),Scalar(10,255,255), thr2); //Create mask to change to avoid background
   thr1=thr1+thr2;

  if(H>255){
     if(H) H-=255;
     thr1.setTo(H,thr1); //Set the image to add to value which will create white color
    // channel[1].setTo(0);
     channel[2]=channel[2]+thr1;
   }

  else {
    H=255-H;
    thr1.setTo(H,thr1);
    // channel[1].setTo(0);
    channel[2]=channel[2]-thr1;//Set the image to subtract from value which will create black color
   }

  //Convert single channel to BGR
  Mat BGR;
  cvtColor(channel[2], BGR,CV_GRAY2BGR);
  imshow( window_name, BGR );


 /* Mat tmp[3] = { channel[0],channel[1],channel[2] };
  merge(tmp,3,dst);
  cvtColor(dst, dst,CV_HSV2BGR);
  imshow( window_name, dst );*/

}
```

In the above code you will get the same result by uncomment the commented code.

**Result:-**
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 Nice, That's how people should answer [tag:image-processing] questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Haris Can i save the S and V of the whole image in a matrix initially and apply this while making color change. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @slaveCoder Using  below code you can get each channel 
     
      
       `cvtColor(src, hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
        Mat channel[3];
        split(hsv,channel); 
    
        channel[0] //hue 
        channel[1] //saturation 
        channel[2] //value`

Comment: @Haris The code works fine.But how can i apply all colors like black ,white etc.

Comment: @slaveCoder You cannot create black and white using hue channel, where you have to use value( val 0 means black and val 255 means white) but that may change your shading.

Comment: @Haris is there anyway i can do this to make a black car with the same effects. I have done using another algorithm to detect red color and then repainting that parts.But it is not having that finish. Currently i am doing for black and white with that algorithm and the output looks like painted. If there is any way to apply shades with black,please let me know.

Comment: @Haris what is H here. Will it differ according to image.The code is working.

Comment: @slaveCoder H is slider position as mentioned in my first code. You can change it from  to  255.