# Imitate Gimp's Hue Adjustment Slider using OpenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to imitate an effect seen in GIMP, which adjusts the hue of an image using OpenCV. The details of the Gimp option can be seen at this link: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-hue-saturation.html , under the *Adjust Selected Slider* title:

> Hue: The slider and the input box allow you to select a hue in the color circle (-180, 180).

The slider is default to 0 (where the image is displayed without changes), and changes of +180 are the same as changes of -180 (for images I looked at, and presumably all). So what I presume is occurring is that Gimp adjusts each pixel's hue value by the selected amount modulo 360.

I've been trying to recreate this effect in OpenCV but I am not having much luck. Here is my code:

```
Mat img = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat imgHSV;
cvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

for (int i = 0; i < imgHSV.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imgHSV.cols; j++) {
        imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = ((imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] + 180) % 360;
    }
}

cvtColor(imgHSV, img, CV_HSV2BGR);

namedWindow("Hue Test", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Hue Test", img);
```

It's also worth noting that I have tried the following and gotten the same results:

```
imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] += 180;
```

You can see the results here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhezA.jpg

You can see the desired result from GIMP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mugd5.jpg

Any help on where I am going wrong would be appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779212/applying-shades-to-an-image-while-applying-color/20786342#20786342

Answer (score 0):

In [OpenCV the Hue range is [0,360]](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor). When the pixels are of depth `CV_8U`, as in your case, the Hue values are "H <- H/2" thus, in the range [0,180].

Thus, assuming your slider value `s` is between [0,180), then each pixel hue `h` would be adjusted as `h = (h+s)%180`.

> **[Note:](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/course/cs4610/references.html)** There are undocumented conversion codes like `CV_BGR2HSV_FULL`, which is similar to `CV_BGR2HSV`, but use the mapping `H <- H*255/360` for hue instead of `H <- H/2` when the output image is 8-bit. This effectively makes the output hue range [0,255] instead of [0,180]; both are compressed down from [0,360] to fit in a byte. Another option is to use 32-bit floating point output, in which case you will get the whole [0,360] hue range.