# Create a mask in iOS

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, mask

I am trying to develop an app in iOS, where the user can try colors on hair.

So the first task is to allow the user select his hair
Second, will be to fill in color in the user selected areas

I've been exploring a lot, but I find links where a geometrical shape can be selected. Can someone point me towards a solution, where I can allow the user select all the areas of his hair in the image he uploaded please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28122143/2317866 Please. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Yes, looked at it, but there the mask images are already given. How do we allow the user to select the area in the image..